# Using Time.now.between? to see if today is between two date periods

Tags: ruby, time

I have a subscription object that has `start_date` and `stop_date` attributes. I want to see if the current day is in between those time frames. I did:

```
Time.now                # => 2018-09-20 22:07:15 -0500
subscription.start_date # => Wed, 19 Sep 2018
subscription.stop_date  # => Fri, 21 Sep 2018
Time.now.between? subscription.start_date, subscription.stop_date # => false
```

`Time.now.between?` doesn't appear to be accurate, and I'm not quite sure why. What is wrong here? This seems like this should work. September 20th is in between September 19th and September 21st, but it's still reading as false.

Comment: Perhaps you have different time zones.

Comment: Are `subscription.start_date` and `.end_date` strings?

Comment: The `start_date` and `stop_date` are date attributes. I think even in different time zones, the dates should still be accurate.

Comment: What do you get when you convert your current time into date?

Comment: `[25] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007f34d55e0c70>>)> Time.now.to_date
=> Thu, 20 Sep 2018`

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it's working if I use `Time.now.to_date.between?`, just not `Time.now.between?` So this seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the fix to my issue. I had to use `Time.now.to_date.between?` instead of `Time.now.between?` After making this change, it finally returned `true` as I expected.

Comment: Instead of `Time.now.to_date` you can use [`Date.today`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today) to get today's date.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. Much appreciated!